# Difference in bounds of convolution integral

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform, convolution

In my ODE class, I was taught that the convolution of two functions is calculated by:
$$\left(f*g\right)\left(t\right)=\int_0^t{f\left(u\right)g\left(t-u\right)du}$$
According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution), the convolution is defined as:
$$\left(f*g\right)\left(t\right)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty{f\left(u\right)g\left(t-u\right)du}$$
and can be simplified to the definition I was taught if the functions $f\left(t\right)$ and $g\left(t\right)$ are only defined for $t\in\left[0, \infty\right)$.
$$$$
It makes sense why the lower bound would become $0$ when the functions are only defined for $t\in\left[0, \infty\right)$, but I am confused why the upper bound becomes $t$ instead of remaining at $\infty$.

1. Wouldn't this change the value of the convolution?
2. If so, do both definitions have the property that $\mathcal{L}^{-1}\left\{F\left(s\right)G\left(s\right)\right\} = \left(f*g\right)\left(t\right)$?

Comment: Implicit in the (one sided) Laplace transform is that the functions are zero for $t < 0$.

Comment: Basically, you not taking the convolution $(f*g)(t)$, but instead $(f\chi_{u\geq0}*g\chi_{u\geq0})(t)$ where $\chi_{u\geq0}$ is the indicator function on the set $\{u\geq 0\}$ which acts a cut off for $u <0$.

Comment: @Dayton Thanks for your help, but the main thing I am wondering is why the $+\infty$ becomes $t$, not why the $-\infty$ becomes $0$.  Sorry if the question was unclear.

Comment: If both functions are supported on $[0,\infty)$ notice that $f(u)$ is zero for $u<0$ and $g(t-u)$ is zero for $u>t$. Their product is only nonzero for $0\le u\le t$

Comment: @Kajelad That answers my question!  Thanks for your help.